# Get count of table disregarding where clause

Tags: mysql

I'm building a collection website, one of things I'm working on at the moment is a query that counts how many games a certain user has in a series, that bit works fine and the below query outputs this:

```html
 <table style="width:100%;text-align:center">
  <tr>
    <th>user_account_id</th>
    <th>series_id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>COUNT(g.id)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Halo</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>Call of Duty</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Forza</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```

```
SELECT uc.user_account_id,
   g.series_id,
   gs.name,
   COUNT(g.id)
FROM user_collections uc
LEFT JOIN games g
ON g.id = uc.game_id
LEFT JOIN games_series gs
ON gs.id = g.series_id
WHERE uc.user_account_id = 1
GROUP BY(g.series_id)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get a full count of all of the rows from my `games` table based on `series_id` information provided in the SELECT portion of my query. So the output instead, would be this:

```html
 <table style="width:100%;text-align:center">
  <tr>
    <th>user_account_id</th>
    <th>series_id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>COUNT(g.id)</th>
    <th>Full Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Halo</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>Call of Duty</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Forza</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```

I've tried doing a sub select query but it looks like you can't do a WHERE clause based off of the column of a select query so I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is `Full Count`? How is it different from the athe `COUNT`?

Comment: `COUNT(g.id)` is how many a user has in their collection. `Full Count` is how many the user _could_ have in their collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a correllated subquery in the SELECT clause

```
SELECT uc.user_account_id,
   g.series_id,
   gs.name,
   COUNT(g.id),
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM games g1 WHERE g1.series_id = gs.id) as `Full Count`
FROM user_collections uc
JOIN games g
ON g.id = uc.game_id
JOIN games_series gs
ON gs.id = g.series_id
WHERE uc.user_account_id = 1
GROUP BY(g.series_id)
```

Comment: Oh, awesome! Thank you, I never thought of that! Your code works fine but I did have to change `g1.series_id = gs.series_id` to `g1.series_id = g.series_id`

Comment: You are right - there is no `gs.series_id`. But `gs.id` should also work.

Comment: @JTP I also changed LEFT JOINs to INNER JOINS. LEFT JOIN doesn't make sense with `GROUP BY(g.series_id)`.